# Is this argument about computers and consciousness logically valid?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, argumentation, consciousness

Assume 1) You can make a conscious agent consisting of a robot controlled by some computer; 2) There are no zombies 3) You replace the computer by a chinese-like room version that behaves identically.

Conclusion: The room plus robot is conscious

Comment: I'm voting to close because while you invoke some basic philosophical language, the idea is poorly developed.

Comment: @Kusin So the Chinese-like room  is conscious?

Comment: @JD then it should be easy for you to point out why the conclusion does not follow from the premises, or are the assumptions somehow not precise enough to you?

Comment: @Kusin Your comment is not constructive in any way, I guess it is just an attack to inflate your ego?

Comment: I could write at length, sure, since I'm interested in AGI. But I'd have to start by pointing out that the argument is informal, and not formal, and therefore the metric that applies to it is not soundness and validity, but strength and cogency, and those metrics would be a function of the definitions "conscious", "zombie", "Chinese-like room", "behavior", and "identically", all of which are philosophical topics unto themselves. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informal_logic

Comment: Don't take it personally. Simply revise to provide your interpretations of conscious, zombie, etc.

Comment: @JD I get it, I am a  physicist and I read crank theories all the time. I just didn't expect that level of precision in philosophy. I read a lot about the subject, and I never got the impression that "zombie" was not well defined, for instance. My bad. I guess I need a PhD in philosophy to even start asking these questions.

Comment: @JD Would this question be ambiguous to someone familiar with the hard problem?  Or is it ambiguous to the non-specialized philosopher only? I am curious, are you a student, a researcher?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148050/discussion-between-j-d-and-pato-galmarini).

Comment: @PatoGalmarini if the robot+computer is conscious in your first premise, the argument is valid. You don’t state this in the assumptions however, you say assume the robot is conscious, and not enough about the consciousness of the robot+computer system in premise 1). It’s not valid currently because of that. Also Premise 2) is unneeded, consciousness entails a non-zombie, but it doesn’t impact the validity with it included, it’s just superfluous. It is a bit informal but I don’t think egregiously